# Iterate over Clojure vector and build up a vector of sets

Tags: clojure, datomic

I am building up a datomic transaction. I have

```
(def codes 
   [:first-code :second-code :third-code])
```

I need to produce a vector of sets in this format:

```
[
  {:db/id (d/tempid :db.part/region)
   :db/ident :first-code}
  {:db/id (d/tempid :db.part/region)
   :db/ident :second-code}
  {:db/id (d/tempid :db.part/region)
   :db/ident :third-code}
]
```

I can't figure out how to do this idiomatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to use `for` comprehension:

```
(let [id '(d/tempid :db.part/region)]
  (vec
    (for [code codes]
      {:db/id id
       :db/ident code})))
```

Or `map` (`mapv` if you specifically want a vector):

```
(let [id '(d/tempid :db.part/region)]
  (->> codes
       (mapv (fn [code]
               {:db/id id
                :db/ident code}))))
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you meant "a vector of maps". The following code should be good:

```
(mapv
  (fn [code]
    {:db/id '(d/tempid :db.part/region)
     :db/ident code})
  codes)
```

Answer (score 1):

I am pretty sure there is an easier way, but this would be a good start:

```
(vec 
  (map #(into {} {:db/id '(d/tempid :db.part/region) :db/ident %}) codes))
```